# Valgrind hangs when reading large HDF5 dataset in Fortran

Tags: linux, fortran, mpi, valgrind, hdf5

I have an application written in Fortran which makes use of parallel HDF5 for input / output.

A matching post-processing code is used to read its output, in the form of a `*.h5` file, and process it.

When I try to use valgrind to check for memory leaks, however, it stalls when reading large datasets.

More exactly, the stalling occurs at a call to `H5Dread_f` for large datasets, for example 1069120 doubles (where doubles are defined as `H5kind_to_type(REAL64,H5_REAL_KIND)`), whereas for smaller ones it is okay.

I tried recompiling the HDF5 library using `--enable-using-memchecker`, as described [here](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/faq/valgrind.html), but it didn't help.

Does anybody have more experience with this?

Comment: Did you try using intermediate size datasets? It may simply be that valgrind is causing the reads to be very slow, and that a test with progressively larger datasets would take steadily longer to complete. If so, you're not seeing a hang - just slowness.

Comment: Doing so would require a rewrite rewrite of the two codes involved. I could do it but it would require some time. I will try later.

Comment: Run a `top` while running valgrind. If it's chewing up CPU, it's probably not hung. Valgrind is notoriously slow, so this is unsurprising.

Comment: I did and it is not stuck. As you said, it just notoriously slow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause / solution: Due to an error of mine, the chunk size I used in these HDF5 routines was often only 1 byte, which is of course much too low.

Fixing this also makes valgrind much much faster and usuable.